# Unable to get Salesforce SOAP API to create in PHP8.1

Tags: php, api, soap, salesforce

I've been using the Salesforce SOAP API for a number of years, but the original PHP client that Salesforce provided doesn't work with PHP8.1.  I've attempted to incorporate the necessary elements of the client into my code since I'm only performing one simple action (creating a QuoteLineItem).  I've been able to get the client to properly connect and login, but my create command doesn't get any response (not even a NULL value).

I've compared everything being sent from the PHP7.4 solution and my 8.1 implementation, and they appear almost identical.

Create statement:
`$result = $this->sforcePartnerClient->create($arg);`

$arg value:
`object(stdClass)#1331 (2) { ["__CLASS__"]=> string(8) "stdClass" ["sObjects"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "\Module\Controller\SObject" } }`

Why am I not getting even an error response?

Comment: Can you show more code? Which client are you using?  It looks like you're sending the string of the object name instead of the object itself, so please show how you're creating `$arg`

Comment: It turned out to be a network problem.  Our salesforce team had changed the domain name for our sandbox instance, and our network was limiting outbound traffic to a whitelist of domain names.  Since test.salesforce.com was in the whitelist, the login was working, but the create was attempting to reach the server specified in the login response, which was not in the whitelist.